# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in $run = $con -> query($query);

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

```
<?php

$name= $_POST['name'];
$roll= $_POST['roll'];

$con= mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("students");

$query = "update classmate SET name= '$name' where roll= $roll";
echo $query;

$run = $con -> query($query);
if($run){
    echo "data Has been Updated";

}
 else {
     echo "Data Has not Updated";
 }

?>
```

Error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in $run = $con -> query($query);

Comment: Check the variable $con, it might be just an error message

Answer (score 0):

To catch connection errors you may use try-catch block:

```
try {
    $con= mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$roll= $_POST['roll'];
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","students");
$query = "update classmate SET name= '$name' where roll= $roll";
echo $query;
$run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($run){
  echo "data Has been Updated";
} else {
  echo "Data Has not Updated";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has a big fat SQL injection vulnerability in it, and should not be used under any circumstances. "It is just an example" is not the best response here - spreading poor security practices can have a real-world impact. Research **parameter binding** and always recommend that, even for examples - it is supported by MySQL and MySQLi.